# Form POST issue

Tags: php, forms, post

I have an issue with a form and submitting it to another .PHP file.

I get a forbidden error when I attempt to post to my database. It will work most of the time, but I get this error when I try to post "http://" links like this:

```
This is a test.<div><br></div><div>I wonder if it will work.&nbsp;</div>
```

Works if there is no br For the above code, I was using a WYSIWYG editor. But this use to happen before the WYSIWYG with certain words.

Not sure if its with the File permissions which is "0644" or the server itself. But I want to fix this. 
Thanks,

I've figured that I cannot use two tags. Such as `<div>Test</div><b>Test</b>` But can use `<div>test</div>`

Comment: a link contains quotes in it's source. Can it be you don't escape your sql in any way? Please see http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

try filtering the post string with:

```
htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']));
```

before you try to insert it to the database.

Comment: The proper place to perform HTML escaping is when using the data, not when storing it.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @ThiefMaster , not true:  performing HTML escaping before saving into database can avoid many sql-injection attacks.

Comment: HTML escaping and SQL injection are **completely unrelated**. To avoid SQL injection usually single quotes have to be replaced with double single quotes or prefixed by a backslash depending on the system. None of these two things happen when html-escaping.

Comment: @ThiefMaster please look at this link: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: Do you see `htmlspecialchars` there anywhere? I don't. In case you confused something: I'm only talking about that function. `mysql_real_escape_string` is obviously required unless you use prepared statements/PDO (which you should)

Comment: Ok, y ment mysql_real_escape_string (confused escaping with the "real_escape")